# Change background color in Menu of MenuBar (Flex 4.6)

Tags: apache-flex, menu, flex3, menubar

In Flex, spark skin's are great. It takes few minutes to customize a component.
Mx components are extremely hard to deal with. It took me 2 days to understand how to change background of Menu in Menubar component. And when I found the right way to accomplish it ( http://goo.gl/Tu5Wc ), it simply doesn't work.
I created very easy application to demonstrate my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            private var menubarXML:XMLList =
                <>
                    <menuitem label="Client">
                        <menuitem label="Profile"/>
                        <menuitem label="Documents"/>
                    </menuitem>
                    <menuitem label="Others">
                        <menuitem label="Profile"/>
                        <menuitem label="Documents"/>
                    </menuitem>
                </>;
            [Bindable]
            public var menuBarCollection:XMLListCollection;
            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                menuBarCollection = new XMLListCollection(menubarXML);

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
        mx|MenuBar.myStyle {
            backgroundColor: #ff0000;
        }
    </fx:Style>
    <mx:MenuBar height="30" labelField="@label" dataProvider="{menuBarCollection}" menuStyleName="myStyle"/>
</s:Application>
```

Can someone explain why Menu background is still white?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Menu Bar itens render a List... Just set, on CSS a style that works with lists (it wont show with ctrl+bar).

```
mx|MenuBar{
    color:#BBBBBB;
    backgroundColor: #333333;
    contentBackgroundColor: #333333;
}
```

Just it! It's easy :D

Answer (score 1):

You can change the CSS for that...

Following is the link for creating the CSS  and use that in current project...

http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html

Select Menubar and start creating you own style. it will also useful to style another components also..

Have a Nice Day -- :)

Comment: Thank you for response, but unfortunately your suggestion won't work. It should be OK for Flex 2, but not for Flex 4. It seems that Adobe has deprecated backgroundColor for MenuBar (see http://goo.gl/Tu5Wc). I am trying to extend and override Menu to fix my problem. If it works, I will post it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came with.

I created a custom MenuItemRenderer, and in the updateDisplayList function I added the following lines:

```
        this.graphics.clear();
        this.graphics.beginFill(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        this.graphics.drawRect(-1, -1, unscaledWidth +1, unscaledHeight+2);
        this.graphics.endFill();

        if (Menu(listData.owner).isItemHighlighted(listData.uid)) { 
            this.graphics.clear();
            this.graphics.beginFill(0xb4c5d6);
            this.graphics.drawRect(0,0, unscaledWidth -2, unscaledHeight-1);
            this.graphics.endFill();        
        }
```

First part is for background and second for roll over effect.

Then I simply extended the standard MenuBar component and overridden the getMenuAt function as follows:

```
    override public function getMenuAt(index:int):Menu
    {
        var menu:Menu = super.getMenuAt(index);
        menu.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(CustomMenuItemRenderer);
        return menu;

    }
```

Probably it is not the best solution possible, but it is the only one I could come up with.
I would like to hear from anyone who could make it better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Found a better option, I think.

Im not using mx lists in my app. So I just used this:

```
mx|List
{
    backgroundColor:#666666;
}
```

Anyway I think you can use inheritance to use this css only for your menu.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it says [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=versioning_4.html) that backgroundColor and backgroundAlpha for MenuBar are depricated

Comment: Its backgroundColor for mxList, not for mxMenuBar.